# Best way to share components of lazy modules between lazy modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a structure of over 20 modules that will have their components shared with each other.
Will I have to import all these components into the shared module? Is there a better structural organization?

Attention I know the concept of shared module. I would like to separate my components into modules and make them talk to each other.

Changed image for better understanding
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have either one shared module or as many shared modules as you want depending on how much shared code you want to separate and how you want to split it.

Let's say you have two lazy modules that share one simple function in two lines. It's useless to create separated chunk for this function because it's better to load it in one single bundle once than having additional request.

On the other hand, if you thing that your initial startup bundle is too big and you know a big amount of code that can be moved to separated chunk, then just do it. Create another shared module that you will import only in two lazy modules which require it.

[image]

There is a great article on this top that will help you understand what it's going under the hood in Angular CLI code-splitting

- [Code-splitting in Angular or how to share components between lazy modules](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-code-splitting-or-how-to-share-components-between-lazy-modules-432c755e389c)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a best practice to create a shared module for dependencies that are shared across all modules or you can create logically separated submodules and import them based on concrete needs.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes?files=1 is a go to for me on making individual modules and combining many individual modules into a larger module. It handles pipes. But it is similar for components.

Customers and Users would be individual modules. And you would make a parent component that consumes both into CustomerUserComponent and facilitates communication between these subcomponents.

NGRX is a really good library built upon rx.js which helps handle communication in a queued fashion. Which becomes powerful when you combine async.